# Elastic Search - Exact phrase search with wildcards

Tags: elasticsearch, spring-data, spring-data-elasticsearch

I am looking for help on exact phrase search with wild card.

```
QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery("Java Se", "title", "subtitle")
    .type(MatchQueryBuilder.Type.PHRASE_PREFIX);
```

The above query, returns the following results.

1) Java Search
2) Elastic Java Search

Trailing wildcard works.

But, When i search like the below query,

```
QueryBuilders.multiMatchQuery("ava Se", "title", "subtitle")
    .type(MatchQueryBuilder.Type.PHRASE_PREFIX);
```

It does not return anything as nothing matches exactly "ava Se".
I was expecting the same result as above.

Leading wildcard does not work.
Is there anyway to achieve this?

Thanks,
Baskar.S

Answer (score 1):

If you have a look at the javadoc for "Type.PHRASE_PREFIX" you will see that only the last term in the string is used as a prefix, thus only "Se" in your case.

I tried this query in my index and it worked: 
`.setQuery(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("body", "(.*?)ing the").type(MatchQueryBuilder.Type.PHRASE_PREFIX))`

It returned documents that contain phrases like "We are strengthening the proposals..", "By using the.."

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [nGram](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html) analyzer or even [edgeNGram](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/analysis-edgengram-tokenizer.html) would be a better idea.
Once you have done that , your index might be a bit heavy but affix search will work fine without wild cards.

Comment: It works fine in the following case without using nGram.

QueryBuilder queryBuilder = boolQuery().should(
                    queryString("Mike Mat").analyzeWildcard(true)
                            .field("firstName", 2.0f).field("lastName").field("title")
                            .field("location").field("industry").field("email"));

Comment: Also, it works for trailing wild card, but not working for leading wildcard.